# xsl:for-each set as single variable?

Tags: xml, variables, xslt, xpath, foreach

I have this working correctly. I am looping through starting at position 3 and separating each addition value with a `;` so I can store the remainder of it in one CSV slot. This works, but I was wondering if there is any way I can store the entire lumped value as one variable along with the `;s`? So than I can later call it below to format my CSV?

My Code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//act/templateId[@root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.4.3']/following-sibling::entryRelationship[@typeCode='SUBJ']/observation">
    <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 2">
        <xsl:value-of select="value/@displayName"/>
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">;</xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Thanks

Comment: With XSLT questions you should always tell us which version of XSLT you are using, since this will often affect the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply wrap you code into `<xsl:variable name="x">`, then render this variable: `<xsl:value-of select="$x"/>` as many times as you want.

Example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>


<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="x">
    <xsl:for-each select="//item">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      <xsl:if test="position() != last()">;</xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:value-of select="$x"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$x"/>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input XML:

```
<root>
  <item>1</item>
  <item>2</item>
  <item>3</item>
</root>
```

Comment: Ah! I just forgot to wrap my code and missed the closing variable. Thank you!